# TransformationResult.transformed SourceFile and ts.Printer

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to transform a TypeScript source file. I'm able to successfully transform the code. In my `TransformationResults.transformed` array there is a `SourceFile`. If I drill down into the `statements` property of the transformed source file, I see my transformed node there and it is what it should be. However, the `SourceFile.text` property does not show the changes made via the transformation.

What should the `SourceFile.text` property be showing, the original text or the transformed text?

Also, using `Printer.printFile` the new file isn't created and the original source file isn't updated. What might I be missing or is my approach all wrong?

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/keithstric/8d2bc4ebf51679d1eb620a17e7e99c79) of the files (index.ts and sample.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured this out, not sure if it's the "correct" way to handle this or not.

`Printer.printFile(ts.SourceFile)` outputs a String with the transformed source code. I just send that to a WriteableStream.